# How can I use input value in Symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller

I create a form in Symfony 5:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('test', TextType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => true
    ])
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $testForm = $form->getData();
    $session->set('testForm',$testForm);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('other_controller');
}
```

Now in other controller I want use `test` value:

```
$testForm = $session->get('testForm');
dd($testForm['test']->getData());
```

But not work. How can I use `test` value?

Error:

> Cannot use object of type App\Entity\User as array

Comment: In real I want get username and password frome register user and first redirect to confirm email and then register user

Comment: @gp_sflover "Cannot use object of type App\Entity\User as array"

Comment: If it is an object (as it should), and if you have property getters in your `User` Entity, then why you didn't use `$testForm->getUsername();`?

Comment: @gp_sflover `test` is an unmapped and `$testForm-.getTest();` not work

Comment: I edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
$testForm = $form->getData();
```

whit this:

```
$testForm = $form['test']->getData();
```